# Mongodb: Remove all document form all collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete all document record from all collection from my database.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete all document in mongodb by simply using `db.collectionName.remove( { } )`

But if your are using node.js, delete all documents by following way.

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/mochatests', function(err, db) {
    db.collection('contacts', {}, function(err, contacts) {
        contacts.remove({}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(result);
            db.close();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: "DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead." I used deleteMany instead of remove. Eg: db.collectionName.deleteMany ( { } ). Thanks @Radhesh for the original answer.

Comment: this delete one from one collection and not all collections

Answer (score -1):

db.collectionName.remove( { } )